# Rally App SDK 2.0: Cannot filter by dates

Tags: javascript, rally

I have tried filtering Portfolio Items by StateChangedDate and LastUpdateDate, but I seem to be unsuccessful.

```
{
    property: 'StateChangedDate',
    operator: '>',
    value: (new Date() - 518400000)
}
```

I have also tried to present it in the same format as retrieved from Portfolio Items, such that the result for comparison is not a value of time in milliseconds.

```
var d = new Date(new Date() - 518400000);

{
    property: 'StateChangedDate',
    operator: '>',
    value: d
}
```

However, neither has worked, and I just end up with no Portfolio Items returned, even though I am absolutely certain that there are items that should pass the filter.

**EDIT**: It looks like I have to use the same format that Rally uses to store them.. 
(i.e.  YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.nnnZ) Is there an easy way to format a date this way? Or would I just have to parse and concat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to use the Rally.util.DateTime.toIsoString function to format your date object. I believe this code snippet does what you're trying to do:

```
var d = Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.DAY, -6);

{
    property: 'StateChangedDate',
    operator: '>',
    value: Rally.util.DateTime.toIsoString(d)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Matt. I think I overlooked that function, as I didn't look into conversion until I realized it had to be in the ISO 8601 format. As an alternative, I had taken the example function from the Mozilla Developer Network, which works fine: http://mzl.la/O0tVVb

However, to simplify things, I guess I will go ahead and use Rally's offering.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this a while ago. It's annoying because the format it's in doesn't work with IE8 (otherwise you could just do something like new Date(yourDate);).

So just create a new Date object and do some string parsing...

```
    a = //your date from Rally here
    b = a.split('T');
    a = b[0];
    c = b[1];
    a = a.split('-');

    year = a[0];
    month = a[1];
    day = a[2];

    b = c.split('.');
    ms = b[1].replace("Z", '');
    b = b[0].split(':');

    hour = b[0];
    min = b[1];
    sec = b[2];

    tmpDate = new Date();
    tmpDate.setUTCFullYear(year, month - 1, day);
    tmpDate.setUTCHours(hour, min, sec, ms);
```